# Understanding Density independence

Tags: android, canvas

I need help understanding the subject. I tried many times to develop something in Android and every single time i get stuck at this.

Currently i have two virtual devices:

- 480x800 mdpi
- 480x800 hdpi

Now in my view with a canvas i want to draw a rectangle with
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

So the results are:

- mdpi rect of 100px (size measured with gimp).
- hdpi rect of 88px (size measured with gimp).

So my question is, if i want to make this rectangle move and control collisions with screen limits how i can get the scale factor that has been applied from density, how i get that the final size of my rect is 88px instead of 100px?

EXTENSION: From this point is it possible that in both devices the rect size will be 100px? What is the formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the rectangle is exactly 100px wide on both devices. What you actually measured was the physical width of the rectangle.

Confused? Let me explain:

The rectangle gets drawn as exactly 100px wide on both devices. They have the same screen resolution, but one has a lower **density**, measured in **dpi** (= dots per inch) or sometimes ppi (= pixels per inch). (In Android, as you might already know *mdpi* means *medium dpi* (~160dpi) and *hdpi* means *high dpi* (~240dpi))
Now, dpi is nothing else than the physical size of one pixel, instead of saying there are 160 pixels/inch you could also say one pixel is 0.something inches big.
That means the physical size of the rect you draw is the width of the rect*size of one pixel. Also, the width of the screen is the resolution in px*size of one pixel. (Actually, the screen of the mdpi device should be displayed smaller than the hpdi device's one)

What happens is that the emulator takes your monitors dpi into account and scales the device accordingly. For your mdpi device it just works out that one device pixel is translated to one monitor pixel, for the hdpi device one device pixel is equal to 0.88 monitor pixels.

In other words, the if these were real phones, the mdpi would have a bigger screen allthough both have the same resolution. The rect would be 100px wide on both but since a pixel on the mdpi phone is bigger the rect would be *physically* bigger. The pixels on your monitor thus actually are the *physical* size of the rect.

If you still have no idea what i'm talking about, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article about supporting different screens in android.

Comment: I still have no idea of what you are talking about, but i appreciate your effort for explaining it to me, and i will look further into the article referenced. Thanks!

Comment: @Deldri one more try: the tl;dr is 100px can be 1inch or it can be 100inch depending on how big one pixel is.

Comment: Yesterday i was unable to understand, but today i read again your post and now i finally understand it. Thank you very much!